# Top Down Unity 3d. Player Only Recognizes One Direction as Forward, Left, etc

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

It says it all in the title, really. I have a blend tree set up with 4 directions and the player moves and rotates perfectly, but if I turn to run directly in (for example) the left direction, the left strafe animation plays while running in that direction. The player is facing in the right direction it is just his legs are playing the wrong animation.
I have tried using "normalized" and "transform.Translate" but nothing seems to make a difference.

```cs
public class TwinStickMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float playerSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float graityValue = -9.81f;
    [SerializeField] private float controllerDeadZone = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] private float gamepadRotateSmoothing = 1000f;

    [SerializeField] private bool isGamePad;

    private CharacterController controller;
    private Animator animator;

    private Vector2 movement;
    private Vector2 aim;

    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    private Vector3 lookPoint;

    private PlayerControls playerControls;
    private PlayerInput playerInput;

    private bool animLocked = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        playerControls = new PlayerControls();
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!animLocked && movement != Vector2.zero)
        {            
            animator.SetFloat("moveX", movement.x);
            animator.SetFloat("moveY", movement.y);
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        playerControls.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        playerControls.Disable();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        HandleInput();
        HandleMovement();
        HandleRotation();
    }

    private void HandleInput()
    {
        movement = playerControls.Controls.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        aim = playerControls.Controls.Aim.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }

    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(movement.x, 0, movement.y);
        controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

        playerVelocity.y += graityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void HandleRotation()
    {
        if (isGamePad)
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(aim.x) > controllerDeadZone || Mathf.Abs(aim.y) > controllerDeadZone)
            {
                Quaternion newrotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(aim.x, 0f, aim.y),Vector3.up); 
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, newrotation, gamepadRotateSmoothing * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(aim);
            Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
            float rayDistance;

            if (groundPlane.Raycast(ray, out rayDistance))
            {
                Vector3 point = ray.GetPoint(rayDistance);
                LookAt(point);
            }
        }
    }

    private void LookAt(Vector3 point)
    {
        Vector3 heightCorrectPoint = new Vector3(lookPoint.x, transform.position.y, lookPoint.z);
        transform.LookAt(heightCorrectPoint);

    }

    public void OnDeviceChange(PlayerInput pi)
    {
        isGamePad = pi.currentControlScheme.Equals("Gamepad") ? true : false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using logic that is equivalent to `if moveX > 0 and moveY approximatly 0 then play strafe animation`. However this doesn't take the players orientation into account and as such only works correctly when you look up. You will need to transform your `moveX` and `moveY` into the localspace of `lookX` and `lookY` so that the animator can make the appropriate choice.

[image: Vectors showing what the animator is presumably getting]

The left panel shows the information your animator is receiving and based on that it is making the wrong choice and says that your character is strafing. The right panel shows the vector after it was transformed. Here your animator would recognize that you are moving forward stronger than sideways and therefore the strafe is inappropriate and the forward walk animation should play.

I'll abridge the math to make it all work and skip to the interesting bits. Basically you want to transform a uv coordinate system into the xy system. For that you have two given perpendicular vectors (look direction and the "right") in the xy coordinates which you can note in two equations like so:

```
x = au+bv
y = cu+dv
```

You can use these to find `u` and `v`, which if you do it will be:

```
u = (by-dx)/(bc-da)
v = (ay-cx)/(cd-ab)
```

Plugging in all the values and inserting the coordinates that you want to transform into `x` and `y` will give you an answer in uv space, which is actually what you need to give to the animator.

Since math is hard and I probably didn't do a particularly good job explaining it, here's the code that does it in Unity:

```csharp
private Vector2 MovementRelativeToLookdirection(){
  float x = movement.x;
  float y = movement.y;
  float a = transform.forward.x;
  float b = transform.forward.z;
  float c = transform.right.x;
  float d = transform.right.z;
  float u = (b*y-d*x)/(b*c-d*a);
  float v = (a*y-c*x)/(c*d-a*b);
  Vector2 transformedVector = new Vector2(u, v);
  return transformedVector;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
  if (!animLocked && movement != Vector2.zero)
  {   
    Vector2 actualDir = MovementRelativeToLookdirection();       
    animator.SetFloat("moveX", actualDir.x);
    animator.SetFloat("moveY", actualDir.y);
  }
}
```

If my assumption is actually the problem this should fix it.

Comment: That's actually an excellent maths lesson. But i fixed it by using  `if (!animLocked)Vector3 localMovement = transform.InverseTransformDirection(movement);` before calling on the animator

Comment: Typical me, brought an artillery piece to scare a sparrow.